# perl: Use map and foreach at once?

Tags: perl

I was wondering if it is possible to make a hash assigning its keys and values at once. Or in general use `map` and `for` at one line:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
%h = map {$_, $i} qw[a b c] for $i (1..3)
```

But unfortunatelly not => `Number found where operator expected`, meant number in the parenthesis. So my question is why am I not able to make double loop by this way? And how otherwise would someone assign hash keys to values (and I dont concern something like `$h = {a=>1,b=>2,c=>3}` but rather assigning `%h = (@keys = @values)` ... in other words, how to assign hash by:

- 2 arrays only (@keys,@values), no scalars
- At once (at one line - without block)

Is it even possible in perl?

Comment: Always `use strict; use warnings;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Populating a hash is simply a matter of assigning a list with alternating keys and values, so you just have to construct the list using the two arrays in an alternating fashion.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @keys = qw(a b c);
my @values = 1..3;

my %h = map { ($keys[$_], $values[$_]) } 0..$#keys;
```

[List::UtilsBy](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::UtilsBy) provides a useful abstraction for this in zip_by.

```
use List::UtilsBy 'zip_by';
my %h = zip_by { @_ } \@keys, \@values;
```

But actually it's even easier to use [slice assignment](https://perldoc.pl/perldata#Slices). Though you technically can't do this in the same statement as the declaration, it's by far the neatest option:

```
my %h;
@h{@keys} = @values;
```

Comment: `($keys[$_], $values[$_])` is usually written `$keys[$_] => $values[$_]` (though this is just a style question)

Comment: FWIW, I use the parentheses in a map statement that returns pairs as a habit to avoid the parser getting confused and treating it as a map EXPR, though it's not always necessary of course.

Comment: `@$_{@keys} = @values for \my %h;` but bad overall idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use `List::MoreUtils 'zip'` or add your own since that module is not a core module:

```
sub zip(\@@){map{($_[0][$_-1],$_[$_])}1..@{$_[0]}}                 
my %h = zip @keys, @values;
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, the question is not very clear on 'why?' -- same can be achieved with following code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $debug = 1;

my %h;

@h{qw(a b c)} = (1..3);

print Dumper(\%h) if $debug;
```